# in_array() always returns TRUE

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arrValue = array('first', 'second');
$ret = in_array(0, $arrValue);
var_dump($ret);
var_dump($arrValue);
```

Above example gives following result:

```
bool(true)
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(5) "first"
  [1]=> string(6) "second"
}
```

Why `in_array()` matches needle 0 to any given haystack?

Comment: See the first comment here: http://nl1.php.net/in_array Add a third parameter `true` in the `in_array` function to set the checking to strict.

Comment: 0 == 'first'; 0 !== 'first';

Comment: You pretty much have to use strict equality with in_array, is the conclusion I've come to, or you'll have  situation like this:  echo in_array('test',['fail' => true]) ? 'WHOOPS' : ''

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's because the function uses a non-strict comparison. The string in the array is compared to integer 0. Some typecasting is happening with data loss, and both are regarded the same:

```
var_dump(0 == 'first'); //  bool(true)
```

So solve this, you can use the third parameter and set it to true to request strict comparison.

```
$ret = in_array(0, $arrValue, true);
```

Keep in mind, through, that strict is really strict. In a strict comparison, `0` is not equal to `"0"`.

Docs: https://www.php.net/in_array

Comment: So `0 == 'first'` got to love PHP.

Comment: can you tell which casts actually make 0 == 'first', thanks

Comment: @Loïc: [this](https://eval.in/111886) or [this](http://3v4l.org/a0nKq) is even better.

Comment: Yeah, you would expect `0` to be typecasted to `"0"`, instead of `"first"` being typecasted to `0`, but that's not how it works. Actually, we should be lucky that `"first"` isn't typecasted to `"1"` and `"second"` to `2`. ;)

Comment: @fast That's a typecast inside the `in_array` function, not one in the code in the question.

Comment: yes, was just a side question.. (so (int) string == 0; ok..) thx :-)

Comment: @DCoder I don't get it! when I change one of the string hashed, I don't get the `true` anymore, what is that black magic?

Comment: @Loic: it might be treated as numbers: "0e..."

Comment: @fast so that would mean, whenever one would use `$a == $b` php interpreter would do `(int) $a === (int) $b` ??

Comment: @Loïc No, only if one of them is an int. If both are strings, then the comparison uses them as-is.

Comment: @Loïc: fast is correct. PHP tries **really hard** to treat a string as a number - it supports exponential notation (`"1e2" == "100"`), octal and hex (`"0xff" == "255"`), floats (`"255.0" == "255"`)... Check out [r/lolphp](http://www.reddit.com/r/lolphp/) for more nightmare fuel. The md5 thing I posted is indeed exponentials, like fast said - they both start with `0e` and contain only digits after that.

Comment: Check out [PHP, a fractal of bad design](http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/) for more nightmare fuel.:)

Comment: @GolezTrol :  PHP is very Idiotic .isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically here 0 treats as false, so the search will occur like the function **in_array** search false between your array value. Make it(0) string to get different output.
As php a support strict or non-strict comparison so you need to pass a third value **true** it tell the to be strict because by default it is non-strict.